# Adding delay to dynamic animation delays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the animation delays on a series of paragraph texts where the actual delays vary between each paragraph.

I've tried the below, but it's not applying the 5 second delay.

Please let me know if you need further information.

```js
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var propval = window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("animation-delay");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.animationDelay = propval + "5s";
}
```

Comment: `10 + "5s" == "105s"`. ... So thats not arithmetic. Other than that, I dont know if the rest of your code would get the desired result anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check your console and you would see the first problem.

You are passing `x` to `getComputedStyle` which expects an element. But `x` is a `HTMLCollection`.

Then you need to properly parse the current delay, and increase its value.

Something like

```js
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var propval = window.getComputedStyle(x[i], null).getPropertyValue("animation-delay");
  var numericPropVal = parseInt(propval,10)
  x[i].style.animationDelay = `${numericPropVal + 5}s`
}
```

```css
p {
  animation: slide 2s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
```